# usb0 ethernet on 10.04.3 Server

Tags: 10.04, usb, ethernet

I am installing Ubuntu 10.04.3 on IBM System x3400 M3 which is listed as certified for Ubuntu 10.04.

I was unable to configure Broadcom netxtreme II Gigabit Ethernet Driver bnx2 during that point. While troubleshooting for that, I noticed  that the IP address I given during install got tied to usb0. Since I am first time coming across usb0 as an ethernet device, I thought of asking here. If I can assign an IP address to a USB port, how I can use it to communicate across network? Or is there any other use of having usb ethernet?

Answer (score 0):

Once the USB network adapter has been configured and detected by the kernel it will show up as any other network interface card would on your computer.

typing:

```
dmesg
```

in the console will output the last logged event. Then insertion and creation of a new network device would show up in the end of this list.

You can assign IP Addresses to the USB network device in the same way you do to any network interface card.